# PHP: Connecting to a database in a static method

Tags: php, mysql, oop, static

I want to add a static method to my class that connects to my database and returns an array of data. E.g., I have a table called Users and a class called User, and I want to be able to call $user = User::fetch($id) to get an array of the specified user's information. So my question is, when and where should I connect to the database? Do I need to pass the database connection information every time I call static methods that serve a similar purpose? That just doesn't feel right.

Comment: No, you don't need to pass database connection information every time. Try the singleton pattern for the db connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i do is have a ConnectionManager class that fires very early in the applications runtime that connects to the relevant database(s) but is using a singleton pattern. So once it's ran once i can access the connection globally throughout the project.

```
use Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager;
use Illuminate\Cache\MemcachedConnector;
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;
use INSP\Config;
use INSP\Core;
use INSP\Di;

/**
 * Class ConnectionManager
 *
 * @package INSP\Database
 */
class ConnectionManager
{

    /**
     * @var \Illuminate\Database\Connection
     */
    protected static $instance;

    /**
     * Loads database configuration from static file if it exists if not it loads from
     * Wordpress defaults
     *
     * @param bool $config
     */
    public function __construct($config = false)
    {
        /*
         * If config is not provided in the constructor check for a config file in the
         * config directory, if that doesn't exist use the database config from wp_config
         */
        if (!$config && file_exists(Core::baseDir() . '/Config/database.php')) {
            $config = include(Core::baseDir() . '/Config/database.php');
        } else {
            if (!defined('DB_HOST')) {
                if (file_exists(Core::baseDir() . '/local-config.php')) {
                    define('WP_LOCAL_DEV', true);
                    require_once(Core::baseDir() . '/local-config.php');
                } else {
                    require_once(Core::baseDir() . '/production-config.php');

                }
            }
            $config = array(
                'driver'    => 'mysql',
                'host'      => DB_HOST,
                'database'  => DB_NAME,
                'username'  => DB_USER,
                'password'  => DB_PASSWORD,
                'charset'   => DB_CHARSET,
                'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            );
        }

        return self::connect($config);

    }

    /**
     * This method is in charge or setting up all connection's including
     * the k2 and mocked testing connection(uTest)
     *
     * @param $config
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Connection
     */
    public static function connect($config)
    {
        $capsule = new Capsule();
        // Load some ancillary configurations
        $k2Config = Config::getAll('Apis/k2');
        $unitConfig = array(
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => ':memory:',
            'prefix'   => ''
        );
        // Add all needed configurations to connections and name them if needed
        $capsule->addConnection($config);
        $capsule->addConnection($k2Config, 'k2');
        $capsule->addConnection($unitConfig, 'uTest');

        // Add capsule to global namespace so we can use it later
        $capsule->setAsGlobal();

        // Start the caching library so we can use the remember(ttl) method in our queries
        $container = $capsule->getContainer();

        $cacheConfig = Config::getAll('cache');
        $memcachedServers = Config::get('cache.memcached');

        $container['memcached.connector'] = new MemcachedConnector();
        $container['config']['cache.driver'] = $cacheConfig['driver'];
        $container['config']['cache.path'] = $cacheConfig['file']['directory'];
        $container['config']['cache.connection'] = null;
        $container['config']['cache.table'] = 'cache';
        $container['config']['cache.memcached'] = $memcachedServers;
        $container['config']['cache.prefix'] = $cacheConfig['prefix'];

        // If Memcached is not installed default to file storage
        if (!class_exists('Memcached', false)) {
            $container['config']['cache.driver'] = 'file';
        }

        // Start Dependency Injection if it hasn't already been started
        Di::init();
        $cacheManager = new CacheManager($container);

        Di::set('cacheManager', $cacheManager);

        $capsule->setCacheManager($cacheManager);

        return $capsule->connection();
    }

    /**
     * @param bool $config
     *
     * @return ConnectionManager
     */
    public static function init($config = false)
    {
        if (!is_object(self::$instance)) {
            self::$instance = new ConnectionManager($config);
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

}
```

This is my connection manager that uses larvels database classes outside of the framework. once this is ran i have another Facade that is literally

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;

/**
 * Class DB
 * This is a Facade of the Connection established by ConnectionManager
 *
 * @package INSP\Database
 */
class DB extends Manager
    {
    }
```

Which lets me use `DB::table()`....... instead of `Manager::table()`.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You need you make a connection the first time you need it, and close the connection when the application is shutting down (`__destruct` method or `register_shutdown`)